# Convergence of a sequence by induction: $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n+1}{x_n+a},x_1>0,a>0,n=1,2,...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Assume that $x_n>0$ and prove $x_{n+1}>0$

$x_{n+1}=1-\frac{a-1}{x_n+a}$

$x_n+a>a$

$-\frac{a-1}{x_n+a}>-\frac{a-1}{a}\Rightarrow x_{n+1}>0$

Is it necessary to find upper bound to prove that sequence is bounded?

$x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{-x_n^2-x_n(a-1)+1}{x_n+a}\le 0$ and sequnce is non-increasing, thus is convergent.

Edited:

I used Banach contraction principle.

Let $f(x)=\frac{x_n+1}{x_n+a}$ and $f(x)$ is a contraction on $[0,+\infty)$

$|f(x)-f(y)|=|\frac{xy+xa+y+a}{(x+a)(y+a)}|$

$\frac{1}{(x+a)(y+a)}\le \frac{1}{a^2}$

By Banach contraction principle, ${x_n}$ is convergent.

Is this correct?

Comment: It is not true that the sequence is necessarily non-increasing.  If $x_n$ is below the positive root of your quadratic numerator then $x_{n+1}>x_n$.

Comment: Your calculation of $f(x)-f(y)$ is incorrect, and $f$ is not necessarily a contraction on $[0,\to)$. If $a=0.1=x$ and $y=0$, then $f(x)=5.5$, $f(y)=10$, and $|f(x)-f(y)|=4.5>0.1=|x-y|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have to consider three cases: $0<a<1$, $a=1$, and $a>1$. The case $a=1$ is trivial: $x_n=1$ for $n\ge 2$.

Suppose that $0<a<1$ and $x_n>0$. Then $0<x_n+a<x_n+1$, so $x_{n+1}>1$. Thus, $x_n>1$ for $n\ge 2$.

Now suppose that $a>1$ and $x_n>0$. Then $a-1>0$, so

$$0<\frac{a-1}{x_n+a}<1\;,$$

and hence

$$0<1-\frac{a-1}{x_n+a}=\frac{x_n+1}{x_n+a}=x_{n+1}\;.$$

In this case we must have $0<x_n<1$ for all $n\ge 2$.

Since $x_n$ is positive, the algebraic sign of

$$x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{x_n+1}{x_n+a}-x_n=\frac{1+(1-a)x_n-x_n^2}{x_n+a}$$

is the same as the algebraic sign of $1+(1-a)x_n-x_n^2$. The parabola $y=1+(1-a)x-x^2$ opens down and has $x$-intercepts at

$$x=\frac{1-a\pm\sqrt{(1-a)^2+4}}2\;,$$

one of which is positive and the other, negative. Let

$$L=\frac{1-a+\sqrt{(1-a)^2+4}}2$$

be the positive intercept; then $x_{n+1}>x_n$ if $x_n<L$, and $x_{n+1}<x_n$ if $x_n>L$. Note also that $L<1$ when $a>1$, and $L>1$ when $0<a<1$.

Suppose that the sequence converges, say to $x$; then

$$x=\lim_nx_n=\lim_nx_{n+1}=\lim_n\frac{x_n+1}{x_n+1}=\frac{x+1}{x+a}\;,$$

so $1+(1-a)x-x^2=0$, and (since $x$ must be positive) we must have $x=L$. This suggests that we might want to investigate the ‘errors’ $x_n-L$ to see whether they converge to $0$.

For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $r_n=x_n-L$. Then

$$r_{n+1}=x_{n+1}-L=\frac{r_n+L+1}{r_n+L+a}-L=\frac{r_n(1-L)+(1-a)L+1-L^2}{r_n+L+a}=\frac{r_n(1-L)}{r_n+L+a}\;.$$

Clearly the algebraic sign of $\frac{1-L}{r_n+L+a}$ is the same as that of $1-L$, so $r_{n+1}$ and $r_n$ have the same sign when $L<1$, and opposite signs when $L>1$.

Suppose that $a>1$. Then $L<1$, and the numbers $r_n$ all have the same sign. Thus, all are negative if $x_1<L$, and all are positive if $x_1>L$. Equivalently, if $x_1<L$, then $x_n<L$ for all $n$, and if $x_1>L$, then $x_n>L$ for all $n$. On the other hand, we saw above that $x_{n+1}>x_n$ when $x_n<L$ and $x_{n+1}<x_n$ when $x_n>L$. Thus, the sequence is monotone increasing and bounded above by $L$ if $x_1<L$, and monotone decreasing and bounded below by $L$ if $x_1>L$, so it must converge, and we’ve already seen that in that case the limit must be $L$.

The case $0<a<1$ is a little harder: in this case the terms $x_n$ are alternately larger and smaller than $L$, so the sequence is definitely not monotone. However, $L>1$ and $r_n+L=x_n>1$ for $n\ge 2$, so for $n\ge 2$ we have

$$|r_{n+1}|=\left|\frac{r_n(1-L)}{r_n+L+a}\right|=|r_n|\cdot\frac{L-1}{x_n+a}<|r_n|\cdot\frac{L-1}{1+a}\;.$$

Now

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{L-1}{1+a}&=\frac{-1-a+\sqrt{(1-a)^2+4}}{2(1+a)}\\
&=\frac12\left(\frac{\sqrt{(1-a)^2+4}}{1+a}-1\right)\;,
\end{align*}$$

and it’s easy enough to take the derivative with respect to $a$ check that this is a decreasing function of $a$ on $[0,1]$, so for $0<a<1$ we have

$$\frac{L-1}{1+a}<\frac12\left(\sqrt5-1\right)<\frac34$$

and hence $|r_{n+1}|<\frac34|r_n|$. It follows that $|r_n|<\left(\frac34\right)^{n-1}|r_1|$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, so $\lim_nr_n=0$, and $\lim_nx_n=L$.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more direct idea is to show that $L$ is attractive fixed point of $f$. This is enough to show that $f'(L)<1$, which is not very complicated.